scp using ProxyCommand and RemoteCommand
I want to scp files from my local machine to a remote machine that needs a JumpHost - via ProxyCommand - and a RemoteCommand on the remote machine to become another user. To ssh to the remote machine i use the command

ssh abremote

and those are the configs i use in my .ssh/config:
Host abremote*
    Hostname abremote.domain
    ProxyCommand ssh -q -W abremote.domain:port ab-hop
    RequestTTY no

Host abremote
    RemoteCommand sudo -u user123remote -i

Host ab-hop
    User user123me
    Hostname ab-hop.domain
    ServerAliveInterval 120
    IdentitiesOnly=yes
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/control:%h:%p:%r

Using the ssh config entry like this:

scp file.txt abremote:/folder_1/folder_2/

it does not work. To use the ProxyCommand in the scp is not the problem, but is it possible to also execute the remoteCommand from a scp call?

Some insight: the preliminary note, the links therein and the whole answer here. Now the question is: do you want/have to use SCP or SFTP?
